# Bootstrap fixed nav-bar doesn't stay width of the page when scrolling?

Tags: java, spring-boot, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

My bootstrap nav-bar is fixed to the top of the page and it is the width of the page as displayed in the image below.

[image]

However when I scroll down the page my fixed nav bar suddenly changes size and it is no longer the width of the page. How do I fix this?

[image]

Here is the code for my nav-bar:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
          <lik rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-3">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="userProfile1">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-3">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <li><a href="/calendar">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="/subjectSearch">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>

      </ul>

      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @Themes.guide bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add class like navbar-fixed-top in your code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

...

Comment: I added that in and it worked except It's slightly covering the first item below the nav-bar rather than being above it if that makes any sense

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

Refer : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar